# Problema na formatação de pergunta editada

Tags: bug, status-aceito, design

Parece-me que a formatação aqui esta errada, certo?

<kbd>[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]</kbd>

Comment: Mais uma tag para me confundir: "formatação". Você não [havia me dito](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3762/separador-sobrepondo-r%C3%B3tulo-no-novo-perfil?noredirect=1#comment9803_3762) para usar "design"?

Comment: Esqueci-me :D @Math